# Difference between except: and except Exception:

Tags: python

Is there any difference between
`except:`
and `except Exception:` ?

Can `except` deal with anything that is not an exception?

Comment: No, they are functionally identical :-)

Comment: Actually, I take that back -- they are different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Python 2.5, there is a new `BaseException` which serve as base class for `Exception`.  As result, something like [GeneratorExit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit) that inherents directly from `BaseException` would be caught by `except:` but not by `except Exception:`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `BaseException`. One important thing that `except:` catches that `except Exception:` does not is `KeyboardInterrupt`. Liberal use of bare `except:` may make it hard to stop your scripts!

Comment: That is correct. [KeyboardInterrupt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) also inherits from BaseException.

Comment: SystemExit also inherits from BaseExcrption

Answer (score 0):

This is from the doc

> If an exception occurs which does not match the exception named in the
>   except clause, it is passed on to outer try statements; if no handler
>   is found, it is an unhandled exception and execution stops with a
>   message as shown above.

You can even be more specific.

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Here, you enter except clause only if you are facing the named error, `ValueError`